# Rails grouped_collection_select и filterrific

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Использую gem [filterrific](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific) для фильтрации в каталоге.

views формы фильтров:

```
= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f|
  = f.select( :with_category_id, @filterrific.select_options[:with_category_id], { include_blank: '- Any -' } )
  = f.select( :with_subcategory_id, @filterrific.select_options[:with_subcategory_id], { include_blank: '- Any -' } )       
  = link_to( 'Reset filters', reset_filterrific_url )
```

контроллер adwerts:

```
  def index
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      Advert.where(published: true),
      params[:filterrific],
      select_options: {
        with_category_id: Category.where(published: true).options_for_select,
        with_subcategory_id: Subcategory.where(published: true).options_for_select,
      },

    ) or return

    @adverts = @filterrific.find.page params[:page]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{ e.message }"
      redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) and return
  end
```

модeль adwerts

```
filterrific(
    default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'created_at_desc' },
    available_filters: [
      :with_category_id,
      :with_subcategory_id,
    ]
  )

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subcategory

  scope :with_category_id, lambda { |category_id|
    where(category_id: [*category_id])
  }

  scope :with_subcategory_id, lambda { |subcategory_id|
    where(subcategory_id: [*subcategory_id])
  }
```

модель category

```
  has_many :subcategories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :adverts

  def self.options_for_select
    order('LOWER(title)').map { |e| [e.title, e.id] }
  end
```

модель subcategory

```
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :adverts

  def self.options_for_select
     order('LOWER(title)').map { |e| [e.title, e.id] }
  end
```

Как заменить в views для subcategory subcategory на grouped_collection_select? Надо сгруппировать в списке подкатегорий по категориям.